# Type conversion issue with 'std_ulogic' - seeking guidance

Tags: vhdl, fpga, xilinx, vivado

I'm working on a VHDL project involving button presses, and I've encountered an issue that I can't seem to crack. In the following line of my code:

```
button_counts(i) <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(button_counts(i)) + 1);
```

I'm getting an error that says, *"type conversion does not match type 'std_ulogic'."* I've double-checked my types and everything seems to be in order, yet this error persists.

Here's a bit of context: I'm using VHDL with Xilinx Vivado, and I'm trying to increment a button count when a certain condition is met. The error specifically points to the conversion of the button count from unsigned to std_logic_vector.

My code:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

entity Clock_24hr_with_Buttons_Memory_Days is
    Port ( 
      clk : in STD_LOGIC;
      reset : in STD_LOGIC;
      buttons : in STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);
      seconds : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(5 downto 0);
      minutes : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(5 downto 0);
      hours : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0);
      day_of_week : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0);
      recorded_seconds : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(5 downto 0);
      recorded_minutes : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(5 downto 0);
      recorded_hours : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(4 downto 0);
      recorded_day_of_week : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(2 downto 0);
      record_button_pressed : out STD_LOGIC;
      button_numbers : out STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0)
    );
end Clock_24hr_with_Buttons_Memory_Days;

architecture Behavioral of Clock_24hr_with_Buttons_Memory_Days is
    type Days is (Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday);
    signal current_day : Days := Monday;

    signal sec_count : integer range 0 to 59 := 0;
    signal min_count : integer range 0 to 59 := 0;
    signal hr_count : integer range 0 to 23 := 0;

    signal record_sec : integer range 0 to 59 := 0;
    signal record_min : integer range 0 to 59 := 0;
    signal record_hr : integer range 0 to 23 := 0;
    signal record_pressed : STD_LOGIC := '0';

    type PressRecord is record
        pressed : STD_LOGIC;
        seconds : integer range 0 to 59;
        minutes : integer range 0 to 59;
        hours : integer range 0 to 23;
        day_of_week : Days;
    end record;

    type PressArray is array (0 to 8) of PressRecord;  -- One counter for each button
    signal button_presses : PressArray;
    signal button_counts : STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(8 downto 0);

begin
    process(clk, reset)
    begin
        if reset = '1' then
            sec_count <= 0;
            min_count <= 0;
            hr_count <= 0;
            button_counts <= (others => '0');
            current_day <= Monday;
        elsif rising_edge(clk) then
            sec_count <= sec_count + 1;
            if sec_count = 60 then
                sec_count <= 0;
                min_count <= min_count + 1;
                if min_count = 60 then
                    min_count <= 0;
                    hr_count <= hr_count + 1;
                    if hr_count = 24 then
                        hr_count <= 0;
                        current_day <= Days' succ(current_day);
                        if current_day = Saturday then
                            current_day <= Monday;
                        end if;
                    end if;
                end if;
            end if;

            for i in 0 to 8 loop
                if buttons(i) = '1' then
                    record_pressed <= '1';
                    record_sec <= sec_count;
                    record_min <= min_count;
                    record_hr <= hr_count;

 
                    if button_counts <= "1001111111" then  -- "1001111111" is the binary representation of 999
                        button_counts(i) <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(button_counts(i)) + 1);
                        button_presses(i) <= (pressed => '1', seconds => record_sec, minutes => record_min, hours => record_hr, day_of_week => current_day);
                    end if;
                end if;
            end loop;

            if buttons = (others => '0') then
                record_pressed <= '0';
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

    seconds <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(sec_count, 6));
    minutes <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(min_count, 6));
    hours <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(hr_count, 5));
    day_of_week <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(Days'pos(current_day), 3));

    recorded_seconds <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(record_sec, 6));
    recorded_minutes <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(record_min, 6));
    recorded_hours <= std_logic_vector(to_unsigned(record_hr, 5));
    recorded_day_of_week <= (others => '0');  -- Replace with your recorded day logic
    record_button_pressed <= record_pressed;
    button_numbers <= button_counts; 

end Behavioral;
```

I'd greatly appreciate any insights, suggestions, or even alternative approaches to resolve this issue. If anyone has experienced a similar problem or can offer guidance on what might be causing this type conversion mismatch, please share your thoughts.

I've double-checked my types and everything seems to be in order. I've attempted to review the code, ensuring that the types match, but the error persists. I was expecting the code to successfully increment the button count for each button press.

Comment: The error is likely due to the fact that `button_counts(i)` is declared as type `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR`, and the conversion from unsigned to `STD_LOGIC_VECTOR` involves a potential mismatch.

Comment: We cannot help as long as you not specify, what you want to do in the line which causes the error message. At the moment it seems that you try to count by using only a single bit of button_counts in each loop, which cannot work. Perhaps button_counts should be an array of std_logic_vectors?! Remove the usage of std_logic_arith and std_logic_unsigned as they are replaced by numeric_std.

Comment: You have included both `std_logic_arith` and `numeric_std` packages. They both declare type `unsigned` and hence the compiler doesn't know which to use and makes them both invisible. Xilinx is not great with error messages for stuff like this. The answer is to delete the non standard `std_logic_arith` package.

Answer (score 0):

I find at least three important issues in your code.

The first issue is related to how you use `button_counts`, as the error message indicates. `button_counts` is defined as a 9 bit `std_logic_vector`. You use `button_counts` in the following statement:

```
button_counts(i) <= std_logic_vector(unsigned(button_counts(i)) + 1);
```

In that statement you do the following:

1. `button_counts(i)` selects bit `i` from `button_counts`. A single bit from an `std_logic_vector` signal is a `std_logic` signal. So your bit is a `std_logic` signal.
2. The `std_logic` signal is converted into a 1 bit unsigned signal using the `unsigned()` function.
3. The integer value 1 is added to the 1 bit `unsigned(0 downto 0)` signal. The result of this operation is an unsigned signal. `numeric_std` defines that the result has the same length as the original unsigned signal (1 bit). So the new unsigned value is also 1 bit long.
4. The 1 bit unsigned signal is converted to `std_logic_vector` using the `std_logic_vector()` function. So the result is now a 1 bit `std_logic_vector(0 downto 0)`.
5. This is where it gets problematic. The 1 bit `std_logic_vector(0 downto 0)` is assigned to bit `i` in `button_counts`. But bit `i` in `button_counts` is a single bit of type `std_logic`. You can not assign a `std_logic_vector` signal to a `std_logic` signal. You must pick a single `std_logic` bit from the 1 bit `std_logic_vector`.

One hacky way to fix this assignment is to select bit 0 from the 1 bit unsigned result. An `unsigned` signal is made up from one or more `std_logic` bits, so you can directly fetch a single bit from an `unsigned` signal, just like you would from an `std_logic_vector`. To do this, you also need to make an intermediate variable that you can slice into.

```
process (clk, reset)
   variable button_counts_i : unsigned(0 downto 0);
begin
   ...
   button_counts_i := unsigned("" & button_counts(i)) + 1;
   button_counts(i) <= button_counts_i(0);
```

This solution compiles, but I do not think it is a nice solution. This brings me to the next issue in your code. You have a lot of numerical outputs from your entity, like `seconds`, `minutes`, `buttons_numbers`, etc. They are all defined as `std_logic_vector`. This was an OK way to define numeric signals before `numeric_std` came around, but today you should always strive to let numeric signals be either `unsigned` or `signed`, not `std_logic_vector`. That will save from a lot of headache, conversion and bugs, and make your code much more readability.

Some people might tell you that inputs and outputs from entities shall always be `std_logic` or `std_logic_vector`. This is a very old-fashioned and outdated way of specifying signals. The intent is most likely to avoid things like `integer` inputs and outputs, or other non-synthesizable types. However, the `numeric_std` types `unsigned` and `signed` are completely synthesizable and very well supported by tools. The only place where you can usually not use them, it on the top level entity (chip_top) that interface the real world with I/O cells.

The third issue has already been mentioned by Tricky. You should never ever use `STD_LOGIC_ARITH`/`STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED` and `NUMERIC_STD` in the same entity. They should not even be used in the same project. You should only use `NUMERIC_STD`, and never use `STD_LOGIC_ARITH`/`STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED`. The `STD_LOGIC_ARITH`/`STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED` packages are outdated packages that turned out to be a dead-end that is both confusing and dangerous to use. See https://nandland.com/vhdl-math-std_logic_arith-vs-numeric_std/

With those three topics addressed, I would recommend you to do the following:

- Stop using `STD_LOGIC_ARITH`/`STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED`. All your needs are covered by `NUMERIC_STD` when you use it correctly.
- Use `signed`/`unsigned` signals as inputs/output on your entity if the signals actually carry numeric information. That saves you from a lot of conversion back and forth.

The proposed solution to your error message is sort of a hack. I do not really understand what you intend to achieve with the logic that you have written there. The way the code is written, you increment one of the bits by 1 when a button is pressed. So since it is a single bit, it will toggle between the values 0 and 1. Is that the intended outcome?

I would rather think that you want to keep track of the number of times each of the 8 buttons are pressed. In that case, you need a two-dimensional signal:

```
type t_button_counts is array (0 to 8) of unsigned(8 downto 0);
signal button_counts : t_button_counts;
```

There you have a signal of 9 unsigned values, where each value is 9 bits each. Then you can write something similar to you original loop:

```
for i in 0 to 8 loop
   if buttons(i) = '1' then
      if button_counts <= 999 then
         button_counts(i) <= button_counts(i) + 1;
      end if;
   end if;
end loop;
```

Notice how simple and clear the code becomes when signals are defined as `signed`/`unsigned`. If you really need a 1 bit counter for each signal, you can change the unsigned definition to `unsigned(0 downto 0)`.

Edit: Also note that 9 bits is not enough to represent the unsigned integer value 999. You need at least 10 bits for that. So you might need to increase the unsigned width from 9 to 10 bits in my suggestion.